# Replace characters in string Java

Tags: java, string, character

I'm trying to use a method to replace certain characters with other characters in a string via parameters, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public String replaceLetter(String word, char letterToReplace, char replacingLetter)
{
    String word2 = word.replaceAll("letterToReplace", "replacingLetter");
    return word2;    
}
```

Comment: [`word.replace(letterToReplace, replacingLetter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-).

Comment: Reading the javadoc of the methods and classes you're using is the way to understand why you get the error, and which other method you could use.

Answer (score 1):

[String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) should do exactly what you described.

```
System.out.println("foo".replace('f', 'b'));
```

will print:

```
boo
```

So in your case:

```
public String replaceLetter(String word, char letterToReplace, char replacingLetter)
{
    String word2 = word.replace(letterToReplace, replacingLetter);
    return word2;    
}
```

even though you could just use `.replace(char, char)` as described above.

Answer (score -1):

```
public String replaceLetter(String word, String letterToReplace, String replacingLetter)
{
    String word2 = word.replaceAll(letterToReplace, replacingLetter);
    return word2;    
}
```

or, if you need to pass `char` to the method

```
public String replaceLetter(String word, char charToReplace, char replacingChar)
{
    String letterToReplace = String.valueOf(charToReplace);
    String replacingLetter = String.valueOf(replacingChar);
    String word2 = word.replaceAll(letterToReplace, replacingLetter);
    return word2;    
}
```

Comment: Try this with `'.'` as the `letterToReplace`.